# Firestore INTERNAL UNHANDLED ERROR in chrome 53

Tags: firebase, google-chrome

I am trying to debug my webOS app in chrome 53 because this is the browser that webos uses so its easy for me to check everything but I am getting a firebase error. Firebase is working fine in other browsers and even in webOS (I checked by installing app on tv) But not in this browser. Is there any solution about this?

[Screenshot showing all the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPUmt.png) (Ignore the first error)